# Why is brave.Tracer not autowired?

Tags: spring-boot, zipkin, brave

We have a lot of services using Spring Boot 2.0.x and `io.zipkin.brave.Tracer` is used and it works properly. Tracer is used in a class annotated with @Component and it has a constructor with Tracer as its parameter.
Here's an example snippet:

```
@Component
public class CrmMessagePublisher {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CrmMessagePublisher.class);

    private static final String EVENT_NAME_HEADER = "service.eventName";

    private static final String EXCHANGE_EVENT = "service.event";

    private static String applicationName;

    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private Tracer tracer;

    @Autowired
    public CrmMessagePublisher(
            RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate,
            @Value("${spring.application.name}") final String applicationName,
            Tracer tracer
    ) {
        this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
        CrmMessagePublisher.applicationName = applicationName;
        this.tracer = tracer;
    }
...
```

Now I want to write a junit test but I always get

```
Test ignored.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:97)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassTestDescriptor.java:349)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:215)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassTestDescriptor.java:349)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1621)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassTestDescriptor.java:348)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:270)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$3(ClassTestDescriptor.java:263)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$4(ClassTestDescriptor.java:262)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$before$0(ClassTestDescriptor.java:192)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.before(ClassTestDescriptor.java:191)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.before(ClassTestDescriptor.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'crmMessagePublisher': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'brave.Tracer' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:847)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'brave.Tracer' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1662)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1221)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    ... 66 more
```

Here's the test class:

```
//@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {RabbitMqTest2.RabbitTestConfig.class, CrmMessagePublisher.class, Tracer.class})
////@EnableRabbit
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class RabbitMqTest2 {

    private final String QUEUE_NAME = "crm-test-service";

    @Autowired
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    private RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin;

    private Binding binding;

    private Queue queue;

    @Autowired
    private CrmMessagePublisher publisher;
//    private Tracer tracer;

    @BeforeAll
    void beforeAll() {
        rabbitAdmin = new RabbitAdmin(this.connectionFactory);
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEachTestCase() {
        // TODO: Get values from test configuration
        connectionFactory.setUsername("admin");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("admin");
        connectionFactory.setHost("localhost");
        connectionFactory.setPort(5672);

        rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);

        rabbitTemplate.setDefaultReceiveQueue(QUEUE_NAME);  // for receiving messages
        rabbitTemplate.setRoutingKey(QUEUE_NAME); // for sending messages

        Properties queueProps = rabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(QUEUE_NAME);
        if( queueProps == null ) {
            queue = new Queue(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, true);
            rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);

            binding = BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(new FanoutExchange("service.event"));
            rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(binding);
        }

        queueProps = rabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(QUEUE_NAME);
        Assert.assertEquals("More messages than expected are in the queue.", 0,
                Integer.parseInt(queueProps.getProperty("QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT") == null ? "0" : queueProps.getProperty("QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT")));
    }

    @AfterEach
    void afterEachTestCase() {
        rabbitAdmin.removeBinding(binding);
        rabbitAdmin.deleteQueue(QUEUE_NAME);
    }

    @Test
    void sendMessageToQueue() throws JsonProcessingException {
        final CrmMessageModel message = new CrmMessageModel();
        message.setCustomerId(1L);
        final AmqpAdmin rabbitAdmin = new RabbitAdmin(this.rabbitTemplate.getConnectionFactory());
        final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("service.event", "contract-service", om.writeValueAsString(message));

        final Properties queueProps = rabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(QUEUE_NAME);
        Assert.assertEquals("Not exactly ONE message is in the queue.", 1,
                Integer.parseInt(queueProps.get("QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT").toString()));
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class RabbitTestConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Bean
        public CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
            return new CachingConnectionFactory();
        }

        @Bean
        public RabbitTemplate crmRabbitTemplate() {
            return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        }

        @Bean
        public RestTemplate crmRestTemplate() {
            return new RestTemplate();
        }

    }
}
```

So: What do I have to do to run the test successful?

Comment: is `brave.Tracer` a bean? Where do you configure `Tracer`?

Comment: I don't configure it at all. It's a third party class and it should work as with CachingConnectionFactory which is a third party class as well.

Answer (score 4):

I hit the same problem; fixed it by ensuring that `spring.sleuth.enabled=true` when running tests.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me to check the most obvious thing!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the tracer `Tracer.class` in your `@ContextConfiguration` does actually nothing:

- it's not a `@Configuration` class
- it does not have a constructor with arguments, which spring could somehow autowire

You should use `org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.TraceAutoConfiguration.class` instead, which provides a working instance of `Tracer`, which could be autowired.

Answer (score 1):

Please try change your testing class line from:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {RabbitMqTest2.RabbitTestConfig.class, CrmMessagePublisher.class, Tracer.class})
```

to

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {RabbitMqTest2.RabbitTestConfig.class, CrmMessagePublisher.class, TraceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: whats the fqcn for TraceAutoConfiguration.class?

Comment: are you looking for https://javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/2.0.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/TraceAutoConfiguration.html ?